# Make a file run every time before shutdown

Tags: windows-7, windows

As far as we know, we can make a file run every time after turning on the windows, by putting it in `Startup` folder or make a key in registry with its path in the value!

Now I want to now, is there any way to make a file run right before Windows shutdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what version of Windows you are running (Professional onwards) you can put a script in the "shutdown scripts" in local Group Policy.